# TextMate RubyAMP bundle, error: "invalid multibyte char"

Tags: ruby, textmate, textmatebundles

I've installed the bundle, but when I'm trying to use option-shift-m (jump to method), I'm getting a weird error message:

```
/tmp/ruby-amp-978.rb:18: invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII)
/tmp/ruby-amp-978.rb:18: invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII)
/tmp/ruby-amp-978.rb:18: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting '}'
  grepper.title = "Searching for method “#{ m }”"
                                          ^
```

Google led me to [this](http://code.google.com/p/ruby-amp/issues/detail?id=17), which unfortunately didn't work out for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to escape qoute sign...

`grepper.title = "Searching for method \"#{m}\""`

Comment: Sorry I've mistyped the code in my question. It's `“#{ m }”` instead of `\"#{ m }\"`. Also note that, this is a tmp ruby file, so fixing code there probably won't help.